# Conditionally allow rotation of single view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make it so that one view controller in my app can conditionally be rotated to landscape.

The VC can show a video stream, in which case I want it to be able to rotate to landscape so the video can take up the full screen. However if the user dismisses the video I want it to only locked to portrait. The user could choose to show the video again in which case I'd need to to be able to rotate to landscape.
I currently have something like this set up.  I have a protocol called `Rotatable` which can be implemented by a VC.

```swift
protocol Rotatable: AnyObject {
  func allowRotation() -> Bool
}
```

In my `AppDelegate` I'm overriding this function:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    guard let controller = topViewController(for: window?.rootViewController) as? Rotatable else {
        return .portrait
    }

    return controller.allowRotation() ? .allButUpsideDown : .portrait
}
```

And in my VC that can optionally show a video I have:

```swift
  func allowRotation() -> Bool {
    videoController != nil
  }
```

This works fine as long as there is a video and the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask` function returns `.allButUpsideDown` Every time I rotate my phone I see this function being called and the `allowRotation()` in my VC being called. Every time.

Except after I dismiss the video my `allowRotation()` will return false and the delegate function in my `AppDelegate` returns `.portrait` and then neither of these functions will ever be called again for the life of the view controller. If I start a new video and then rotate the screen neither function gets called and the app stays in portrait.

Any ideas here? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to call `setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()` after dismissing the video view controller.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't seem to do anything. Also that only works on iOS 16 but I'll need to support 14 and 15 as well. Basically need a way to force the app delegate method to be called again